# Should we answer questions if the answers can be found elsewhere on the site?

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-questions

I have this confusion all the time, I see people posting some questions which aren't exactly duplicate to other questions on Stack Overflow but with a little google search, the answer can easily be found on stack overflow for those questions. So should we answer those questions or flag them?

Comment: Sometimes people answer the question beause they cannot find a duplicate, or because they are not sure that it will be closed. It happens that we see the same person *both* write a short answer and vote to close the question. That's ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the rep, vote to close as an exact duplicate. If you don't, put a comment pointing to the duplicate, and others will pick it up and VtoC (I think this will be just as quick as flagging for a moderator, depending on how niche the subject matter is). Repeating the same answers doesn't really help anything, even if you repeat *all* of the answers and *all* of the comments. This just splinters the knowledge. Keeping the duplicate question closed can be helpful if the wording or content is significantly different (it can direct users to the same answers even if they used different search terms).

Comment: as i said before, the questions aren't exactly duplicate, but if they do a little google search they can easily get their way to similar questions on stack over flow, so in that case flag or answer?

Comment: That depends, if the questions are different but the ANSWERS still solve the question, then vote to close as duplicate. If the answers on the old question don't solve the new question, then regardless of how the question is worded, it doesn't sound like a duplicate to me.

Comment: okay, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: If the answer to another question is likely to be useful (because it's related) but is not actually an exact duplicate, you can just post a comment with the link and something like "related question".  If you wanted to, you could post an answer with a summary of that link, and what needs to be done to turn that related answer into a solution for the OP.